# How to load javascript files from cache when changes not done in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, caching, optimization

I have appended timestamp values to javascript files to load fresh copy from server each and every time page is loading.

```
<script>document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='Script1.js?v=" + Date.now() + "'><\/script>");</script>
<script>document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='Script2.js?v=" + Date.now() + "'><\/script>");</script>
```

But I want to load fresh copy from server when changes made in the javascript files. When changes not done in the javascript files I want to load the javascript files from cache. How to do that?

Comment: Instead of a date you could simply use a incremental number - you have `src='Script1.js?v=" + Date.now()` simply `Script1.js?v=1`,  `v=2` etc. I know it sounds tedious, but how on earth should the browser know the remote script has been changed _without_ reloading it? So you must help the browser to only reload a file when it has a new version number.

Comment: @davidkonrad, How can I identify script file is changed in the server?

Comment: the job should make the browser and server. Server usually sends information to browser, when the particular file was changed, so the browser can skip loading if it has the last version already

Comment: @Daniel, When user manually clears browser cache, then only he/she gets lastest javascript file changes in browser. How browser will identify latest version?

Comment: @RGS at least this is the way it should work. read here about status code 304 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection